# Compiling MacOS application with CGL

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, cmake

I'm developing C++ application on Mac and use CGL for initialising OpenGL:

```
EGL_CONTEXT EglWrapperMac::CreateContext() {
    EGL_CONTEXT context;
    if (kCGLNoError != CGLCreateContext(m_display, NULL, &context)) {
        throw EXT_EXCEPTION(EGL_WRAPPER_ERROR_CREATE_CTX);
    }
    return context;
}
```

Also I use Cmake to produce XCode solution.
Unfortunately build fails due to lack of required libraries. I was trying the following statement in cmake:
 `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -framework CGL -framework OpenGL")`
and `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lCGL -lOpenGL")` with no luck.

**Update:** Here are the errors of compilation:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "_CGLChoosePixelFormat", referenced from:
      EglWrapperMac::EglWrapperMac(EglSetup const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<IEngineWindow>) in libVEngineRenderer.a(EglWrapper.o)
  "_CGLCreateContext", referenced from:
      EglWrapperMac::CreateContext() in libVEngineRenderer.a(EglWrapper.o)
  "_CGLDestroyPixelFormat", referenced from:
      EglWrapperMac::~EglWrapperMac() in libVEngineRenderer.a(EglWrapper.o)
  "_CGLFlushDrawable", referenced from:
      EglWrapperMac::Present() in libVEngineRenderer.a(EglWrapper.o)
  "_CGLGetCurrentContext", referenced from:
      EglWrapperMac::GetCurrentContext() in libVEngineRenderer.a(EglWrapper.o)
  "_CGLReleaseContext", referenced from:
      EglWrapperMac::DeleteContext(_CGLContextObject*) in libVEngineRenderer.a(EglWrapper.o)
  "_CGLSetCurrentContext", referenced from:
      EglWrapperMac::MakeCurrent(_CGLContextObject*) in libVEngineRenderer.a(EglWrapper.o)
```

How can I handle that?

Comment: How about you show the errors you're getting?

Comment: There is no CGL framework in OS X (CGL is included in the OpenGL framework, you need only `#include OpenGL/OpenGL.h`), and you do not use `-lXXX` to link against a framework either. Now, depending on how your Makefile is structured, you may also have a property known as LD_FLAGS for a separate linking stage - you **also** need to include `-framework OpenGL` there. This directive does *both*, include path resolution and linker path resolution for frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for help. I was able to resolve the problem with the following code in cmake:

```
include_directories ( /System/Library/Frameworks )
find_library(OpenGL_LIBRARY OpenGL )
set(EXTRA_LIBS ${OpenGL_LIBRARY})

//add_library (VEngineRenderer STATIC ${RENDER_FILES})

target_link_libraries(VEngineRenderer ${EXTRA_LIBS})
```